# How do I get past the final barriers in "The Real World"?

Tags: pc, saints-row-iv

In Saints Row IV, I am currently stuck in the story mission "The Real World". I can't seem to get past the final barriers, every time I try, the second barrier closes long before I make it through.

Is there a technique to it, or am I just doing something wrong? (Or both?)

Comment: Included the PC tag because the flight controls are much different on PC - this would probably be much easier to accomplish on console.

Comment: I changed the tag from PC to keyboard, as many people play PC games with a controller and not the mouse and keyboard which what you seems to be using and what you think the problem is.

Comment: [This issue has apparently been fixed.](http://steamcommunity.com/games/206420/announcements/detail/2109096234909112413)

Comment: Though in-game testing after the fact shows otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the PC, try turning your graphics down to "low". From what I read elsewhere, if your settings are turned up too high it causes the doors to close more quickly than they should. I was having the same trouble, turned the graphics to "low", and made it through on my first try.

Comment: Hmm. Weird. But this worked. I also recommend binding a couple of keys to "roll left" to allow sideways flight, but that may not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also drop your screen resolution down to a lower setting if that still doesn't work.

Comment: How does dropping screen resolution resolve the issue?

Comment: Based on the patchnotes, this was a framerate issue. A lower screen resolution would not only have not solved this problem, but it would also make everything really distorted.

Comment: @Unionhawk lower resolution = higher framerate.

Answer (score 0):

Use the cheat code `fastforward`.

I just figured it out. Stay in the center at the bottom. Don't even tilt.

Works like a charm.

Comment: I was doing this, but because of performance issues with this particular mission, the second door closed too early.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a key on the pc to either 'roll left' or 'roll right' actions.

It keeps the tilt on while that key is pressed.

Comment: I did this, and it simply did not work, due to technical reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The mod, **[No Gates in "The Real World](http://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/threads/no-gates-in-the-real-world.4529/)"** is an attempt to fix this bug/issue.

Description:

> This mod makes the gates at the end of "The Real World" mission not close at all. This should make it easier for those who have trouble at that part of the game and those who have low spec PCs where the gates close before you can get to them.